# Joining DB tables: repeat values in one table for each group in second table

Tags: sql-server, join, row-number

Students are absent from classes, I have to calculate consecutive absences.  'Date' table has all dates in school year, and indicates if school is in session.  Not in session for weekends or holidays.  'Absence' table lists students and the dates they were absent from specific class. I need to list all dates for each 'CLASS' group to see if a class is missed for consecutive days.  I have tried CROSS JOIN, couldn't get it to work.  Maybe ROW_NUMBER can be used. Any type of solution is welcome!

[image]

Date table with dates school is in session. Absence tables with days a student is absent and which class. Last picture is table I want to create. I would like to repeat the dates in the range for each Student/Class group

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following. You can run this example in SSMS.

```
DECLARE @Absent table ( stu_id varchar(10), class varchar(10), absent_date date );
INSERT INTO @Absent VALUES
    ( 'Billie', 'English', '11/03/2020' ),
    ( 'Billie', 'Math', '11/10/2020' ),
    ( 'Billie', 'Math', '11/12/2020' ),
    ( 'Billie', 'Science', '11/19/2020' ),
    ( 'Billie', 'Math', '11/19/2020' );

DECLARE @InSession table ( CalDate date, InSession bit );
INSERT INTO @InSession VALUES
    ( '11/02/2020', 1 ),( '11/03/2020', 1 ),( '11/04/2020', 1 ),( '11/05/2020', 1 ),( '11/06/2020', 1 ),( '11/07/2020', 0 ),( '11/08/2020', 0 ),
    ( '11/09/2020', 1 ),( '11/10/2020', 1 ),( '11/11/2020', 0 ),( '11/12/2020', 1 ),( '11/13/2020', 1 ),( '11/14/2020', 0 ),
    ( '11/15/2020', 0 ),( '11/16/2020', 1 ),( '11/17/2020', 1 ),( '11/18/2020', 1 ),( '11/19/2020', 1 ),( '11/20/2020', 0 );

SELECT DISTINCT
    FORMAT ( s.CalDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy' ) AS CalDate,
    s.InSession,
    a.stu_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.absent_date = s.CalDate THEN a.class
        ELSE ''
    END AS class,
    CASE
        WHEN a.absent_date = s.CalDate THEN FORMAT ( a.absent_date, 'MM/dd/yyyy' )
        ELSE ''
    END AS absent_date
FROM @InSession AS s
CROSS APPLY @Absent AS a
ORDER BY
    s.CalDate;
```

Returns

```
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
|  CalDate   | InSession | stu_id |  class  | absent_date |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
| 2020-11-02 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-03 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-03 |         1 | Billie | English | 11/03/2020  |
| 2020-11-04 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-05 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-06 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-07 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-08 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-09 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-10 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-10 |         1 | Billie | Math    | 11/10/2020  |
| 2020-11-11 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-12 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-12 |         1 | Billie | Math    | 11/12/2020  |
| 2020-11-13 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-14 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-15 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-16 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-17 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-18 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-19 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-19 |         1 | Billie | Math    | 11/19/2020  |
| 2020-11-19 |         1 | Billie | Science | 11/19/2020  |
| 2020-11-20 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

Note that on `11/19/2020` Billie is marked absent from two classes, creating multiple results for the day.

You will also receive a blank row in addition to an "absent" row on days an absence has been reported. I'm looking to see if I can resolve this part.

**UPDATE**

Removed the "empty" rows on absent days.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        s.CalDate,
        s.InSession,
        a.stu_id,
        ISNULL ( x.class, '' ) AS class,
        ISNULL ( x.absent_date, '' ) AS absent_date
    FROM @InSession AS s
    CROSS APPLY @Absent AS a
    OUTER APPLY (
        
        SELECT
            ab.class, CONVERT ( varchar(10), ab.absent_date, 101 ) AS absent_date
        FROM @Absent AS ab
        WHERE
            ab.stu_id = a.stu_id
            AND ab.absent_date = s.CalDate

    ) AS x
    ORDER BY
        s.CalDate, stu_id, absent_date;
```

Returns

```
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
|  CalDate   | InSession | stu_id |  class  | absent_date |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
| 2020-11-02 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-03 |         1 | Billie | English | 11/03/2020  |
| 2020-11-04 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-05 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-06 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-07 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-08 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-09 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-10 |         1 | Billie | Math    | 11/10/2020  |
| 2020-11-11 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-12 |         1 | Billie | Math    | 11/12/2020  |
| 2020-11-13 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-14 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-15 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-16 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-17 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-18 |         1 | Billie |         |             |
| 2020-11-19 |         1 | Billie | Math    | 11/19/2020  |
| 2020-11-19 |         1 | Billie | Science | 11/19/2020  |
| 2020-11-20 |         0 | Billie |         |             |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

**UPDATE**

*So I want the date range, Nov 2 - 20, repeated for every CLASS and every STUDENT included in the raw data.*

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CalDate,
    InSession,
    stu_id,
    class,
    MAX ( absent_date ) AS absent_date
FROM (

    SELECT DISTINCT
        CalDate,
        InSession,
        stu_id, 
        x.class,
        CASE
            WHEN x.absent_date = CalDate THEN CONVERT ( varchar(10), x.absent_date, 101 )
            ELSE ''
        END AS absent_date
    FROM @InSession AS i
    CROSS APPLY @Absent AS a
    OUTER APPLY (
        
            SELECT
                ab.class, CONVERT ( varchar(10), ab.absent_date, 101 ) AS absent_date
            FROM @Absent AS ab
            WHERE
                ab.stu_id = a.stu_id
                AND ab.absent_date = a.absent_date

        ) AS x
    WHERE
        i.CalDate BETWEEN '11/02/2020' AND '11/30/2020'

) AS StudentAbsent
GROUP BY
    CalDate, InSession, stu_id, class
ORDER BY
    stu_id, class, CalDate;
```

Returns

```
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
|  CalDate   | InSession | stu_id |  class  | absent_date |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
| 2020-11-02 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-03 |         1 | Billie | English | 11/03/2020  |
| 2020-11-04 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-05 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-06 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-07 |         0 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-08 |         0 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-09 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-10 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-11 |         0 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-12 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-13 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-14 |         0 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-15 |         0 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-16 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-17 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-18 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-19 |         1 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-20 |         0 | Billie | English |             |
| 2020-11-02 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-03 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-04 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-05 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-06 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-07 |         0 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-08 |         0 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-09 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-10 |         1 | Billie | Math    | 11/10/2020  |
| 2020-11-11 |         0 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-12 |         1 | Billie | Math    | 11/12/2020  |
| 2020-11-13 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-14 |         0 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-15 |         0 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-16 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-17 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-18 |         1 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-19 |         1 | Billie | Math    | 11/19/2020  |
| 2020-11-20 |         0 | Billie | Math    |             |
| 2020-11-02 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-03 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-04 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-05 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-06 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-07 |         0 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-08 |         0 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-09 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-10 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-11 |         0 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-12 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-13 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-14 |         0 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-15 |         0 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-16 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-17 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-18 |         1 | Billie | Science |             |
| 2020-11-19 |         1 | Billie | Science | 11/19/2020  |
| 2020-11-20 |         0 | Billie | Science |             |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: That is close, I will try to work with it. I was hoping that I could get the Date range, Nov 2 to Nov 20, repeated for each STUDENT/CLASS group. I need to see if there are consecutive absences for each STU/CLASS group.

Comment: I addressed the "empty row" on absences. This does include all dates in `@InSession`, so I don't think I follow your "I was hoping that I could get the Date range, Nov 2 to Nov 20, repeated for each STUDENT/CLASS group." comment.

Comment: Imagine if Billie were a bad student, and was skipping many Eng, Math and Sci classes between Nov 2 and Nov 20.  That table would be very complex and it would be difficult to see exactly how many consecutive days in a row Billie was absent from just his Math class. If the final result set was dedicated to just one STUDENT and one CLASS, it would be easy to see consecutive absent days. So I want the date range, Nov 2 - 20, repeated for every CLASS and every STUDENT included in the raw data. Nov 2-20 for Billie in ENGLISH, Nov 2-20 for Billie in MATH, Nov 2-20 for Billie in SCIENCE.

Comment: Ah, so one class per date range, repeated for every class, by student. Is there a student table, or just the "absent" table?

Comment: Yes, there is a student table, but I dont want all students.  I will generate the 'absent' table at runtime, it is a subset of students. I am sure you can image a student table joined with an 'Absence_Class' table, the result is the 'absence' table I defined. My report user will choose the students and the date range.

Comment: @HenryFramer, see the most recent update to my answer.

Comment: YES, that last snip of code does what I need. I have incorporated it into my solution, it's working.   SOLVED, thanks 'Critical Error'.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
See the last piece of code from Critical Error.